# Send JSON POST request with PHP

Tags: php, json, post, curl, http-post

I have this JSON data:

```
{ 
    userID: 'a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021',
    itemKind: 0,
    value: 1,
    description: 'Saude',
    itemID: '03e76d0a-8bab-11e0-8250-000c29b481aa'
}
```

and I need to post to JSON URL:
http://domain/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Account/CreditAccount

How can I send this POST request using PHP?

Comment: Really, charging an account over _http_! Please use http*s* and a form of JWS to verify who sent it!

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Without using any external dependency or library:

```
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode( $data ),
    'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n"
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );
```

`$response` is an object. Properties can be accessed as usual, e.g. `$response->...`

where `$data` is the array containing your data:

```
$data = array(
  'userID'      => 'a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021',
  'itemKind'    => 0,
  'value'       => 1,
  'description' => 'Boa saudaÁ„o.',
  'itemID'      => '03e76d0a-8bab-11e0-8250-000c29b481aa'
);
```

**Warning**: this won't work if the `allow_url_fopen` setting is set to `Off` in the php.ini file.

If you're developing for WordPress, consider using the provided APIs: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/

Comment: @solarshado raw response headers can be fetched with [stream_get_meta_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php).

Comment: A small improvement suggestion, you could also put the headers in an array, especially if more headers such as Authorization need to be added. In that case, the "\r\n" should *not* be added.

Answer (score 165):

You can use CURL for this purpose see the example code:

```
$url = "your url";    
$content = json_encode("your data to be sent");

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}


curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

Comment: [curl example and user notes in php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

Comment: It's giving brackets syntax error, if we pass json object to json encode function.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that `file_get_contents` solution doesn't close the connection as it should when a server returns `Connection: close` in the HTTP header.

CURL solution, on the other hand, terminates the connection so the PHP script is not blocked by waiting for a response.