# Sending data through curl in a specified format?

Tags: php, node.js, curl

I've the following function to communicate between php and nodejs:

```
function toNode($data){

    //$data is array
    //$data example
    //$data = array("one"=>"yes","two"=>"no","three"=>array("yet"=>"another"))

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:'.$socket_port.'/posts');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_exec($ch);

    $feedback = curl_getinfo($ch);

}
```

Here is how the nodejs **console.log**s the data received:

```
 { one: 'yes',
 two: 'no',
'three[0][yet][0]':'another'}         //<---
```

And here is **how I want the data to appear** in nodejs side:

```
{ one: 'yes',
two: 'no',
three: [ { yet: 'another' } ] }       //<---
```

How exactly can I make this happen with curl? I've tried using this function on received information nodejs side

```
function urldecode(str) {
   return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

but it fails, outputing nothing If I remember correctly. Also, **the function used further to treat the data is shared between what comes from php curl or natively in nodejs (which is not url encoded)** so, the best would be to solve the problem right in php side... Could someone help me here? Thank you very much...

EDIT: including parsing of information nodejs side:

```
app.post('/posts', function(req, res){

   if(req.headers.host == '127.0.0.1:'+socket_port) {
        if(req.method == 'POST') {
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

                res.writeHead(200, [[ "Content-Type", "text/plain"]
                        , ["Content-Length", 0]
                        ]);
                res.write('');
                res.end();

                furtherFunction(fields);                
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: how do you parse the `POST` payload on the `nodejs` side?

Comment: @AlexAndrei sorry, forgot to include that. See edit

Comment: see this https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/220, depending on what `formidable` accepts you could try to send directly a json string as the `POST` payload

Comment: you can also try a more recently updated fork of formidable from here https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty

Comment: Have you tried   `if(req.headers['host'] == '127.0.0.1:'....` ?

Comment: @moskito-x sorry, I didn't understand... the problem is not on checking if the request comes from the localhost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand, you want so send json data. I haven't seen any json data here. I googgled it. Here [send-json-post-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php), i found how to send json data in php. Hope it will help.