# how to redirect after dump json response in php

Tags: php, json, response

I'm trying to create a PHP response script that redirects back to a target URL. unfortunately currently when I redirect, the JSON value is not send together. below code is what I've tried.

```
<?php
  header('Location: https://alia.com/readme.html');
  $data1 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($data1);
  //prints json array ["a","b","c"]
?>
```

I wonder how can I create a php response and redirect back to client page.

Comment: what does https://alia.com/readme.html do with a json, why aren't you posting to that url?

Comment: That will send the json with it. I assume you misunderstood making POST requests?

Comment: @Sbls the client will send post request to server, assume code above is try to response back to client request, i dont include the real logic and url.
currently it only able to redirect to target url. but no json response tie together in the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: application/json', true, 200);
$arrayResponse =array(
    'data'=> array('Ram','Pukar','Developer','PHP',"Java")
);
$encode = json_encode($arrayResponse);
print_r($encode);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: how can i redirect the json respond to target url?

Comment: Use Cookie Or Session.
Reference Stackoverflow Zend Framework:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php