# Json POST To Curl PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

I'm trying to fetch some data from this  json javascript code and print them to PHP using CURL

```
<html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax(
   {
       type:"POST",
       contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
       url:"https://www.bancopromerica.com.gt/wsservicebus/wsonlineservicebus.asmx/getTipoCambio",
       data:"{}",
       dataType:"json",
       async: false,
       success: function(msg) {
          a("#compInter",msg.d.compraInternet); //Compra Internacional
          a("#ventInter",msg.d.ventaInternet); //Venta Internacional
          a("#compAgencia",msg.d.compraAgencia); //Compra Agencia
          a("#ventAgencia",msg.d.ventaAgencia); //Venta Agencia
      },
      error: function(textStatus, errorThrown, errorDetail){
          alert(errorDetail);
      }
   });
function a(a,b)
{
   jQuery(a).append(b);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I receive this error:

> [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" 
>   location: "JS frame :: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js ::
>   .send :: line 4"  data: no]

Do you have any idea how to do this right in PHP ?

Comment: You have a `div` with an `id` of `compInter`. This will have the value `msg.d.compraInternet` appended to it. Is this not working?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? You have some JavaScript and a URL to an ASP.NET web service.

Comment: @steve no i have an error..

Comment: @Quentin i need to use CURL , the ASP.net is just an example that it's working well with webservices, but i need to make it working with PHP

Comment: @rojocuarentaodiso — Are you asking how to do what you are currently doing with JavaScript using PHP/cURL instead?

Comment: Yes!! that's what i'm asking!! @Quentin

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php

Answer (score 2):

I think all of your `JQuery.ajax` is correct(By the way, you can change it to `$.ajax`). The problem that I am thinking is in your`a` function. This is how I think it should look, and how I do it:

```
function a(a, b)
{
    $(a).html(b);
}
```

I have not checked it out on codepin, or jsfiddle, or anything, but I think that will work.

Comment: Thank you, i make the changes but still not  working!

Comment: By the way, whenever I go to your website I get this error: `An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. `

Comment: thank you so much, well that's why i want to consume with Curl PHP becanse aparently this can't be work witht the same origin code, it just can be working with different code, that's  my problem. That's why i want to find a solution to make it work with PHP

Answer (score 1):

A very basic php cURL example would be:

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.bancopromerica.com.gt/wsservicebus/wsonlineservicebus.asmx/getTipoCambio"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch); 

    echo json_encode($output)
```

You would need to `var_dump` the `output` as you will want to assign array key/values that suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what i'm looking for, i'm understanding a little bit more now, i've tried this example right now, it's printing this error : "\r\n \r\n what you think about it?