# Sending json to another domain

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a php file like this:

```
<?php
    //recieving json
    $sJsonData = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $aPostData = json_decode($sJsonData, true);

    //here I need to post the data to another cross domain
    $url='http://www.website.org/recieveJson.php'
    //
    ...
?>
```

Is this possible in pure php?

Its only about the sending (actualy sort of re-sending/redirecting) of json. The retrieving part will I handle myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send json post using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php)

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post