# How to make a PHP POST request with given json

Tags: php, post

POST /authentication/login

Content-Type: application/json

Accept: application/json

{

"dsCredentials": {

```
"tenantName": "...",
"userName": "...",
"password": "...",
"applicationInfos": {
  "applicationName": "...",
  "applicationVersion": "...",
  "serverName": "...",
  "requestID": "..."
},
"mfaCode": "..."
```

}

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php

Comment: Use cUrl library: [Send json post using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213509/send-json-post-using-php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cURL, for example

```
  $data = [
    'username'      => $username,
    'email'         => $email,
    'password'      => $password
];

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

//So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```